# How to correctly handle Byte values greater than 127 in Kotlin?

Tags: types, type-conversion, kotlin

Imagine I have a Kotlin program with a variable `b` of type `Byte`, into which an external system writes values greater than `127`. "External" means that I cannot change the type of the value it returns.

`val a:Int = 128
val b:Byte = a.toByte()`

Both `a.toByte()` and `b.toInt()` return `-128`.

Imagine I want to get the correct value (`128`) from the variable `b`. How can I do it?

In other words: What implementation of `magicallyExtractRightValue` would make the following test run?

```
@Test
fun testByteConversion() {
    val a:Int = 128
    val b:Byte = a.toByte()

    System.out.println(a.toByte())
    System.out.println(b.toInt())

    val c:Int = magicallyExtractRightValue(b)

    Assertions.assertThat(c).isEqualTo(128)
}

private fun magicallyExtractRightValue(b: Byte): Int {
    throw UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented")
}
```

**Update 1:** This solution suggested by [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) seems to work.

```
private fun magicallyExtractRightValue(o: Byte): Int = when {
    (o.toInt() < 0) -> 255 + o.toInt() + 1
    else -> o.toInt()
}
```

Comment: `byte` is signed in Java, so you will have to live with this. Why do you have to use a `byte`? Where is the `int` coming from?

Comment: I have an external library, which I don't want to change. It gives me byte-typed values with negative numbers in them.

Comment: so the library already gives you "-127". Why do you need to convert it? It does not make a difference unless you use it numerically. If you are sure the library really "meant" 128 instead, you could use `short` or `int` on your end of things (convert by doing 255 + b for negative numbers).

Comment: I need the actual numerical value, because in another third-party library that numerical value is used as an index in an array.

Comment: Array indexes are `int`. You can convert from your "unsigned byte" by doing `int x = b < 0 ? 255 + b : b;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Comment: Thanks. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. See also my update 1.

Comment: I couldn't find it before but here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2640946/3255152.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With Kotlin 1.3+ you can use [unsigned types](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2/). e.g. [`toUByte`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-u-byte.html) ([Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/LY0zlB_c6)):

```
private fun magicallyExtractRightValue(b: Byte): Int {
    return b.toUByte().toInt()
}
```

or even require using `UByte` directly instead of `Byte` ([Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/itNJKEWeE)):

```
private fun magicallyExtractRightValue(b: UByte): Int {
    return b.toInt()
}
```

For releases prior to Kotlin 1.3, I recommend creating an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) to do this using [`and`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/and.html):

```
fun Byte.toPositiveInt() = toInt() and 0xFF
```

Example usage:

```
val a: List<Int> = listOf(0, 1, 63, 127, 128, 244, 255)
println("from ints: $a")
val b: List<Byte> = a.map(Int::toByte)
println("to bytes: $b")
val c: List<Int> = b.map(Byte::toPositiveInt)
println("to positive ints: $c")
```

Example output:

```
from ints: [0, 1, 63, 127, 128, 244, 255]
to bytes: [0, 1, 63, 127, -128, -12, -1]
to positive ints: [0, 1, 63, 127, 128, 244, 255]
```

Comment: the eclipse Kotlin plugin somehow doesn't know the bitwise `and`, how else can this be done?

Comment: @Xerus I haven't really used the Eclipse plugin so I'm not sure what to say but I suspect something is misconfigured as `and` is part of "kotlin-stdlib". You might try using it as not infix: `toInt().and(0xFF)`.

Comment: Why is this not baked into Kotlin??!?

Comment: Depending on your data, this is very helpful for a `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`. Thank you.

Comment: For reference, [explanation for why `and` is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071395/539599).

Comment: What if I use kotlin 1.3.20?

Comment: @RajuyourPepe I've updated my answer to be a little more explicit in the usage of `toUByte`, etc. in Kotlin 1.3+ for your use case of 1.3.20.

Comment: Thank you so much, It really helpful in BluettothGattCharacteristics

Answer (score 0):

Good old `printf` does what we want:

```
java.lang.String.format("%02x", byte)
```